# Что означает имя переменной с точкой после имени функции

Tags: python, функции

При поиске информации по декораторам столкнулся с тем, что можно написать вот такой текст (не связано напрямую с декораторами):

```
def func():
    return func.s
func.s=1
print(func())
```

и получить в итоге 1.

Что означает вот эта запись - `func.s`? Что это за переменная? Если попробовать написать `func2.s` (т.е. просто имя с точкой), то будет ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: @Глеб, а почему тогда нельзя написать func2.s ?

Comment: вот такой код не работает:

Comment: def func():
    return 1
func2.s=1

print(func())

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Мой вопрос про python, а не про JavaScript

Comment: Так а с чего он будет работать? ведь `func2` вы не определили.

Comment: Да, я невнимательно вопрос прочитал, это не совсем переменная. Это переменная-атрибут-функции. Точка означает, что это атрибут s функции func.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Питоне практически любая сущность - это полноценный класс. Включая функции и даже просто числа (что далеко не в каждом языке бывает).

```py
def func():
    return func

print(type(func))
print(type(func).__bases__)
```

Вывод:

```
<class 'function'>
(<class 'object'>,)
```

То есть `func` - это объект класса `function`, унаследованного от класса `object` (от которого наследуются все классы Питона).

А у классов и их экземпляров есть атрибуты.

```py
func.s = 1
print(func.__dict__)
```

Вывод:

```
{'s': 1}
```

То есть это просто один из вариантов установить атрибут экземпляра класса. Не самый лучший. Всё-таки атрибуты лучше устанавливать явным образом:

```py
setattr(func, 'x', 1)
```

Таким образом, например, можно устанавливать атрибуты, название которых задано какой-нибудь переменной.

```py
x = 'тест'
setattr(func, x, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

спасибо всем, я понял, что так записываются атрибуты функций.